# wxWidgets wxMessageDialog throwing access violation exception

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have following code:

Main.h

```
#pragma once

#include <wx\wxwidgets.h>

class Main : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Main.h"
bool Main::OnInit() {  
    wxMessageDialog *test= new wxMessageDialog(nullptr, wxT("Test"));
    test->ShowModal();
    return true;
}

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(Main);
```

I'm using wxWidgets 3.0.3 and have set up the project using instructions provided [here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide) (Visual studio 2017).

The interesting part is that I've had `wxFileDialog` work normally, without issues, so I doubt the library isn't set properly.

When I try to execute the above code, I get a Access violation reading location exception at line 594 of `msgdlg.cpp` (which is a part of the library, I'm assuming):

```
int wxMessageDialog::ShowModal()
{
    WX_HOOK_MODAL_DIALOG();

#ifdef wxHAS_MSW_TASKDIALOG
    if ( HasNativeTaskDialog() )
    {
        TaskDialogIndirect_t taskDialogIndirect = GetTaskDialogIndirectFunc();
        wxCHECK_MSG( taskDialogIndirect, wxID_CANCEL, wxS("no task dialog?") );

        WinStruct<TASKDIALOGCONFIG> tdc;
        wxMSWTaskDialogConfig wxTdc( *this );
        wxTdc.MSWCommonTaskDialogInit( tdc );

        int msAns;
--THIS->HRESULT hr = taskDialogIndirect( &tdc, &msAns, NULL, NULL );
        if ( FAILED(hr) )
        {
            wxLogApiError( "TaskDialogIndirect", hr );
            return wxID_CANCEL;
        }

        // In case only an "OK" button was specified we actually created a
        // "Cancel" button (see comment in MSWCommonTaskDialogInit). This
        // results in msAns being IDCANCEL while we want IDOK (just like
        // how the native MessageBox function does with only an "OK" button).
        if ( (msAns == IDCANCEL)
            && !(GetMessageDialogStyle() & (wxYES_NO|wxCANCEL)) )
        {
            msAns = IDOK;
        }

        return MSWTranslateReturnCode( msAns );
    }
#endif // wxHAS_MSW_TASKDIALOG

    return ShowMessageBox();
}
```

I've set a breakpoint and it fails when entering the function. Since `msAns` has just been created, I doubt that's a problem, so the only possible culprit left is `tdc`.

Does any of this make any sense?
How do I make it work?
Is it a bug within the library?

**EDIT:**

After some further inspection, it seems that the issue appears only if I run the x64 configuration. x86 configuration runs perfectly fine.

I know I haven't switched the x86 and x64 binaries since I copied the whole output at once (vc_lib and vc_x64_lib folders, it handles them internally), and besides, I'd expect problems on x86 version while the x64 would work fine in that case, not the other way around.

What gives?

Comment: I compiled the binaries myself, using the same IDE.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem with the minimal/dialog samples? If yes - I'd file a bug with as much information as possible - wx version, Windows version, compiler version. If it is reproducible with you current version, I'd also try the Git HEAD first before filing.

Comment: Also, if you have access to *nix/OSX, I'd try the code there with the sample. BTW, why do you need to display this in the application constructor - why not have wxFrame and do it there?

Comment: Isn't this as minimal as it get? What else could I remove here?
I need to make sure user meets certain conditions, and I check that before I initialize the main frame so I can exit the app without having to deal with closing the main frame.

Comment: first - problem is you will most likely be asked to provide a patch to the sample reproducing the problem. So I'm just trying to help you here. ;-) Second - did you try with the latest sources (aka Git HEAD)? And did you try all other platform? - this will be helpful as well. Third - if you do it in the wxFrame constructor and on failure do `delete this` - you will not need to close anything. Or to do it cleanly - send wxEVT_CLOSE event. It just weird to have it in the application constructor.

Comment: I've tried the latest, 3.1.0 and 3.0.3 and they all fail in the same way, even when I paste my code into the sample projects. It must be something to do with the way x64 librares are being compiled, but I just don't know what...